# Recursive Feature Elimination - Long-Running R Code

Tags: r

I am running recursive feature elimination (RFE) in R using the code below. It never seems to finish on my PC. What options has anyone found useful to get R code, specifically RFE like that noted below, to run faster? Options I'm thinking of include the following (further down).

R CODE (RFE):

```
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, #type of variable evaluation algorithm, e.g., RF
           method = "repeatedcv",
           repeats = 5,
           verbose = FALSE)
subsets <- c(1:5, 10, 15, 18) #most important features to iterate

lmProfile <- rfe(x=lassodf, y=lassodf$isFraud, #x = trainData[, c(1:3, 5:13)] sizes = subsets, rfeControl = ctrl)
```

1. sampling/reducing dataset number of observations
2. sampling/reducing number of variables hardware, i.e., concurrent core processing or
   other settings to ensure max utilization
3. 3rd-party service for running code

Which option(s), including any not listed above, have you found more effective than others to address runtime performance issues with RFE?